# Creating multiple datetime columns for every request per PersonID Python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset consists out of two columns, PersonID and Request for application(Aanvraag datum). Some PersonIDs occur multiple times because these persons received multiple request on different dates:

[image]

Now I want to create multiple request columns per PersonID. For example if a PersonID occurs three times, then the code creates three columns for three different requests dates. If a PersonID occurs one time, the code assigns NaN to the empty requests. In the end there will be as many columns as the PersonID with the most requests.

Example:
[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe), [pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411391/pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas/70411430#70411430)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `append=True` and then [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1), append=True)['Aanvraag datum']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('Aanvraag '))
```